# What's the input of each LSTM layer in a stacked LSTM network?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, stacked

I'm having some difficulty understanding the input-output flow of layers in stacked LSTM networks. Let's say i have created a stacked LSTM network like the one below:

```
# parameters
time_steps = 10
features = 2
input_shape = [time_steps, features]
batch_size = 32

# model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=input_shape,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=input_shape))
```

where our stacked-LSTM network consists of 2 LSTM layers with 64 and 32 hidden units respectively. In this scenario, we expect that at each time-step the 1st LSTM layer -LSTM(64)- will pass as input to the 2nd LSTM layer -LSTM(32)- a vector of size `[batch_size, time-step, hidden_unit_length]`, which would represent the hidden state of the 1st LSTM layer at the current time-step. What confuses me is:

1. Does the 2nd LSTM layer -LSTM(32)- receives as `X(t)` (as input) the hidden state of the 1st layer -LSTM(64)- that has the size `[batch_size, time-step, hidden_unit_length]` and passes it through it's own hidden network - in this case consisting of 32 nodes-?
2. If the first is true, why the `input_shape` of the 1st -LSTM(64)- and 2nd -LSTM(32)- is the same, when the 2nd only processes the hidden state of the 1st layer? Shouldn't in our case have `input_shape` set to be `[32, 10, 64]`?

I found the LSTM visualization below very helpful (found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/animated-rnn-lstm-and-gru-ef124d06cf45)) but it doesn't expand on stacked-lstm networks:
[image: LSTM workings]

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The `input_shape` is only required for the first layer. The subsequent layers take the output of previous layer as its input (as so their `input_shape` argument value is ignored)

The model below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(5, 2)))
model.add(LSTM(32))
```

represent the below architecture

[image]

Which you can verify it from `model.summary()`

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_26 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 64)             17152     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_27 (LSTM)               (None, 32)                12416     
=================================================================
```

Replacing the line

```
model.add(LSTM(32))
```

with

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(1000000, 200000)))
```

will still give you the same architecture (verify using `model.summary()`) because the `input_shape` is ignore as it takes as input the tensor output of the previous layer.

And If you need a sequence to sequence architecture like below

[image]

you should be using the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(5, 2)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
```

which should return a model

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_32 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 64)             17152     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_33 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 32)             12416     
=================================================================
```

Comment: this already helps, but how do you get from 64 to 32? Are you taking only the last 32 of 64 outputs? And how is this going for a deep bidirectional LSTM? the process is only clear to me if you have the same number of LSTM units in each layer ...

Comment: @S.Maria LSTM has input size and output/hidden size. Internally it uses gating mechanism to convert inputs to hidden/outputs. Here my input size is 64 and output size is 32. In case of bi-LSTM you get two outputs one for each direction. So if your output size is 32 you will get 32 for left->right LSTM and 32 for right->left LSTM.

Comment: I have a question, how is the interconnection between the first layer of 64 units and 32 units made?

Answer (score 0):

In keras document, mentioned the input is `[batch_size, time-step, input_dim]`, rather than `[batch_size, time-step, hidden_unit_length]`, so I think 64, 32 coorresponding the X-input's has 64 features and LSTM-32 has 32 features for each time-step.